# Can we filter the Beans creation in Spring Dependency Injection based on annotation conditions

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to achieve something like below. This might be stupid question but I wanted to know if that's possible or any other ways of to do it.

```
-- src
   --test
    --pkg1
       --Pkg1_class1
       --Pkg1_class2
    --pkg2
       --Pkg2_class1
       --Pkg2_class2

    --tests
       --testPkg1
          --Pkg1_TestClass1
       --testPkg2
          --Pkg2_TestClass1
```

I have used **@Component** annotation for all the classes that need to be injected, and it works fine.

But I have a requirement that when I run the tests from **testPkg1**, I want spring DI to create only the beans required for those objects i.e. only for the classes in **pkg1** above. And, the sameway, when I run the tests from testPkg2, I don't want to create beans for the classes inside pkg1 as I don't need them or no intention to use at all for these tests.

I understand that we are telling the spring to scan for the packages that need to be injected. Wondering is there a way we can filter that based on some condition on annotations or something like that.
Please feel free to correct me if my understanding is wrong or the question. Appreciate it.

Comment: Have a look at [Spring Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles).

Answer (score 0):

As @Giorgi Tsiklauri mentioned in comment, you can use profiles or you can use

[EnableAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html)'s exclude property:

```
..
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={Class1ofPkg2.class,Class2ofPkg2.class ,..})
public class YourTestClassofPkg1{
```

Comment: I don't want to specify every class and it will be hard to maintain as I have lot of them, but thanks for the suggestion.

Spring profiles worked well for my case.